# Disable all dates after some months from a certain date Android DatePicker

Tags: c#, android, datetime, datepicker, xamarin

I have two DatePickers in my app. First, shows the FromDate which is `CurrentDate+1`, the second shows the ToDate ie. `FromDate+1`.

I have got the above scenario working. But now I want to disable all the dates after 6 months from the FromDate.
I tried doing the following,but the calender then shows 01/01/1970 as the current date.

BookingActivity.cs

```
void IbtnToDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toDateClicked = true;
            fromDateClicked = false;
            dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment(this,  DateTime.Parse (editFromDate.Text.ToString ()).AddDays (1), this, DateTime.Parse (editFromDate.Text.ToString ()));
            dateFragment.Show(FragmentManager, null);
        }

        void IbtnFromDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fromDateClicked = true;
            toDateClicked = false;
            dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment(this, date.AddDays (1), this, date.AddDays (1));
            dateFragment.Show(FragmentManager, null);

        }


        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            var date1 = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);

            if (fromDateClicked)
                UpdateFromDate (date1);
            else if (toDateClicked) {

                UpdateToDate (date1);
            }
        }
```

DatePickerFragment.cs

```
 public class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment
    {
        private readonly Context _context;
        private DateTime _date, _minDate, _maxDate;
        private readonly Android.App.DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener _listener;

        public DatePickerFragment(Context context, DateTime date, Android.App.DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener listener, DateTime minDate)
        {
            _context = context;
            _date = date;
            _listener = listener;
            _minDate = minDate;

        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
        {

            var dialog = new Android.App.DatePickerDialog(_context, _listener, _date.Year, _date.Month - 1, _date.Day);
            dialog.DatePicker.MinDate =_minDate.AddDays (1).Millisecond;
            dialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = _date.AddMonths(6).Millisecond;
            return dialog;
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Means you do not want to show old dates??

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I do not want to show the future dates after 6 months from the From date.

Comment: I have updated my answer than it will run perfectly...so please check my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setMaxDate` and can do something like:

1- Get the date from _mindate string:

```
  String dateString = "03/26/2012";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2- Get date of 6 months from min_date:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(convertedDate);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
Date 6MonthsFromCurrentDate = cal.getTime();
```

3- Restricting the datePicker to that date:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(6MonthsFromCurrentDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. But could you explain me your answer with respect to my question

Comment: @user3034944 check now. Hope it helps.

Comment: This works. But it disables the 6 months from the current date. How can I disable it from the _minDate?

Comment: convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString), I stll get the Current date even if the dateString is the date I selected

Comment: may be the wrong date format...what format are you using....and whats the date_string?

Comment: Are you sure, its not going to the catch for ParseException?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong format. I was using MM-dd-yyyy. Your code works. Thank you. Accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines of code.

```
        Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
        String CiDateTime = ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
            (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 7) + "-" + //for 6 month future
            ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        Date d;
        try {
            d = f.parse(CiDateTime);
             long milliseconds = d.getTime();
            _date.setMaxDate(milliseconds);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.but it doesnot work.  The future dates are not disabled

Comment: Means...Future date after 6 month is not disable or Current future date is not disable??

Comment: Future 6 months are not disabled